# Enforce that a code snippet is always present on a set of Java classes

Tags: java, aop, static-code-analysis

I have to be sure that a snippet of code get executed in all public methods of classes under a certain package:

```
public String doStuff(String a, Integer b, Context c) {
   current.put(c); <--- code that need to be executed
   // business logic
   ...
}
```

What would be the best approach for ensuring that that snippet of code is always present **AS THE FIRST LINE** of each public method?

I have  considered using some static code analysis tool, such as PMD. Also, I believe compile time AOP could help. Any more idea, pointers?

I know that I can use an Aspect for that. Problem is that my application is using Spring but the classes I need to "check" are not spring managed - also, I'd like to avoid changing the server start options to enable Spring annotation based run time weaving.

EDIT:
The classes I have to enforce the code on are [Akka](http://akka.io/) Typed Actors.

Comment: For the snippet of code, are they implementing interfaces?  Perhaps Java's dynamic proxy (http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) could help if this is the case.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is your purpose to do a pre-condition check, logging or something else?

Comment: Yes, all the classes where I have to "enforce" the check implement an interface.

Comment: @blitzpasta: is audit trail, I need to pass a "Context" object to the next layer and I'm planning to use ThreadLocal for that. The snippet has to put the current context into the threadlocal.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to pass a "Context" object to the next layer and I'm planning to use ThreadLocal for that. The snippet has to put the current context into the threadlocal.

If you're using Spring, have you considered making the context a thread-scoped bean?  If this is through a HTTP request, you can use **scope="request"** on the bean and Spring will manage things for you (including passing a request-scoped bean to a singleton).

You can easily create a more general thread scope.

Comment: Yes, I have looked into that but creating a simple Context helper class is very easy too. I will try this approach anyway (one less class to mantain ;) )

Answer (score 0):

PMD is a good option. Besides you can integrate it with IDE and all developers will be notified.

Another option is to add some step to your build process that will either modify the source code using some regular expression (or Java parser - PMD has one as well) or add some byte code generation using libraries like ASM or JavaAssist that will post process your code after it is compiled.

If you can use AspectJ then you can also use that to post-process your class files after they are compiled to check/add some code.

If you can control this class creation using some Factory implemetation, then you can create a dynamic proxy around the created instances.